# cakephp 2 favicon load after 75s

Tags: php, performance, cakephp-2.3, favicon

I have a loading speed problem with a website developed with Cakephp 2.3
Indeed, the first file loads quickly but the favicon.ico file is loaded after 75 seconds. (see image). have you any idea?
thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NDYA.jpg

Comment: In your image `favicon` take `812 ms` which is `0.000812 seconds` not `75` seconds

Comment: sorry, actually it' is load 75s after the last